I want to monitor the nvme dirver submission queue depth
I do some fio workloads in nvme ssd for checking arbitration mechanism. In some case, arbitration mechanism in nvme ssd is wrong effect.
So i want to monitor nvme drive submission queue. I search some contents in stackoverflow and find this posting
But i review the source code of nvme driver, this nvme_sq event don't occur in timing that driver sumits request. Below code is /drivers/nvme/host/pci.c(linux-6.2.5)
static inline void nvme_handle_cqe(struct nvme_queue *nvmeq,
                   struct io_comp_batch *iob, u16 idx)
{
    struct nvme_completion *cqe = &nvmeq->cqes[idx];
    __u16 command_id = READ_ONCE(cqe->command_id);
    struct request *req;

    /*
     * AEN requests are special as they don't time out and can
     * survive any kind of queue freeze and often don't respond to
     * aborts.  We don't even bother to allocate a struct request
     * for them but rather special case them here.
     */
    if (unlikely(nvme_is_aen_req(nvmeq->qid, command_id))) {
        nvme_complete_async_event(&nvmeq->dev->ctrl,
                cqe->status, &cqe->result);
        return;
    }

    req = nvme_find_rq(nvme_queue_tagset(nvmeq), command_id);
    if (unlikely(!req)) {
        dev_warn(nvmeq->dev->ctrl.device,
            "invalid id %d completed on queue %d\n",
            command_id, le16_to_cpu(cqe->sq_id));
        return;
    }

    trace_nvme_sq(req, cqe->sq_head, nvmeq->sq_tail);
    if (!nvme_try_complete_req(req, cqe->status, cqe->result) &&
        !blk_mq_add_to_batch(req, iob, nvme_req(req)->status,
                    nvme_pci_complete_batch))
        nvme_pci_complete_rq(req);
}

So is there any other method for monitoring the nvme drive submission queue depth?
